# make Draggable not return when its canceled

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a  draggable container which can be dragged around the screen. The problem i faced that Draggable always returns to it's prevouis postition.https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4PTH.jpg
So how can you create Draggable that stays at the position where you left of your finger.

Comment: Don't make it cancel. Make the canvas a `Stack` that takes the draggable and sticks it at the position where the draggable was dropped.

Comment: Can you show the Widget Tree? I Wrapped the Draggable in a Stack but i didn't work out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **onDraggableCanceled** property to change the location.

i hope that following example will clear your idea.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double width = 100.0, height = 100.0;
  Offset position;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    position = Offset(0.0, height - 20);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Positioned(
          left: position.dx,
          top: position.dy - height + 20,
          child: Draggable(
            child: Container(
              width: width,
              height: height,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "Drag",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            feedback: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  "currently dragging",
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline,
                ),
              ),
              color: Colors.blue[300],
              width: width,
              height: height,
            ),
            onDraggableCanceled: (Velocity velocity, Offset offset) {
              setState(() => position = offset);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i tried it with onDraggableCanceled to but i didn't knew what to pass in.

Comment: I would recommend to change the position in the initState function from```height - 20``` to  ```height + 10```  and int the Positioned Widget from ```position.dy - height + 20```  to ```position.dy - height - 10```

Comment: You don't have to pass anything over there. You get the offset, so that you can set your widget's position. I it working as expected in your question.